# Diabetic and anxiety

Tags: dogs, anxiety, diabetes

My dog has been diagnosed with diabetes. Today he will not let me pet him he just starts yelping. When my husband came near him he climbed on my lap but when I touched him he started yelping. I know he has anxiety issues as well. Could this be that he is telling me he does not want any more injections. I do not know what to do he is breaking my heart and I do not know what to do to comfort him. Or could this mean there is something more going on.

Comment: Does he yelp wherever you touch him or only when you touch him in a particular spot (like the neck)? The former is an indication of general anxiety, the latter a sign of severe pain caused by a physical problem that should be checked by a vet.

Comment: we sometimes are not touching him at all just near him. I would say when we do touch him it is all over. Of course we back away as soon as he starts except to try to reassure him that everything will be okay

Comment: You should contact your vet.

Comment: I agree. If this yelping started today, you should get him checked by a vet as soon as possible.